# Azure Devops Checkout - Hook already exists: pre-push

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml, git-lfs

I have a pretty simple process:

```
  - checkout: self
    clean: ${{ parameters.cleangit }}
    persistCredentials: true
    lfs: true
    submodules: true
    fetchDepth: 0
```

When I run pipeline for the first time - everything looks good. Second time with the same branch - all good. But when I changed branch from Dev to main, I got the error:

Hook already exists: pre-push

```
#!/bin/sh
command -v git-lfs >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "\nThis repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting '.git/hooks/pre-push'.\n"; exit 2; }
git lfs pre-push "$@"
```

> To resolve this, either:   1: run `git lfs update --manual` for
> instructions on how to merge hooks.   2: run `git lfs update --force`
> to overwrite your hook.
> ##[error]Git-lfs installation failed with exit code: 2

I tried parameter "clean" - no luck.
Any ideas how to fix it and use git lfs?

Comment: Did you try using `clean: true`?